# How to remote download the latest JDK8 from putty

Tags: java, unix

I am tryng to download the JDK8 from remote machne from putty using below command but I am gettiing error.What would be the correct command to download the JDK?

wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz

However,I am getting below error:

**--2020-07-01 05:41:26--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 184.87.216.29
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|184.87.216.29|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2020-07-01 05:41:26--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 104.100.27.112, 2600:1408:8c00:78f::366, 2600:1408:8c00:78d::366
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|104.100.27.112|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1593582206_c008aca005712c7ac40bf44fd8b35b44 [following]
--2020-07-01 05:41:26--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1593582206_c008aca005712c7ac40bf44fd8b35b44
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|184.87.216.29|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1593582206_c008aca005712c7ac40bf44fd8b35b44 [following]
--2020-07-01 05:41:26--  https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u25-b17/jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1593582206_c008aca005712c7ac40bf44fd8b35b44
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|184.87.216.29|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-07-01 05:41:27 ERROR 404: Not Found.**

Comment: Do you need to get Oracle JDK specifically?  Cannot you use get OpenJDK using commands like `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk` ?

Comment: If it resolves to a 404, that's not a problem on your end -- the resource simply doesn't exist at the specified location on the server end. Unless you can hack Oracle's servers, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: What is new JDK download url now so that we download?

Comment: I got the solution.I transferred the JDK software from local machine to remote using WinSCP tool.Thanks